# Renaming a bunch of files by truncating at a certain point

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I need to rename a bunch of music files from `Artist - Title [FREE DL].mp3` and `Artist - Title [FREE DL] [PREMIERE].mp3` to just `Artist - Title.mp3`

I have this, but it isn't working and I can't quite tell why.

`find . -type f -name "* - * \[*\].mp3" -o -name "* - * \[*\] \[*\].mp3" -execdir bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do new=${file% \[}.mp3; mv -v "$file" "$new"; done' _ {} +`

Due to not being a bash wizard, I can't quite get it to fix. I know the find is finding the files, but rename isn't doing anything and trying oto echo `$new` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Several things wrong:-

- The reason nothing is coming out is because `-o` doesn't do anything else if the preceding expression matches - this includes both trying to match the second `-name` **and** performing the subsequent `-execdir`; but the first expression is matched for both styles of file name, so nothing further is done. If you do need to match two different file masks, use brackets `\( -name ... -o -name ... \)`, but in this case you are best simply to remove the `-o` and the second `-name` clause.
- Once `-execdir` is being executed, there are two things wrong with the file name expansion:

  - `${file% \[}` deletes any trailing blank and open square bracket from the file name - there aren't any (all the file names end in `p3`);
  - you need `${file% \[*}` to include the rest of the file name, but this still isn't good enough, because a single `%` matches the *shortest* possible string, ie only from the *last* blank and open square bracket - to match from the first you need `${file%% \[*}`, which matches the longest possible string.

So what you need is:

```
find . -type f \( -name "* - * \[*\].mp3" -o -name "* - * \[*\] \[*\].mp3" \) -execdir bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do new=${file%% \[*}.mp3; mv -v "$file" "$new"; done' _ {} +
```

or, more simply:

```
find . -type f -name "* - * \[*\].mp3" -execdir bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do new=${file%% \[*}.mp3; mv -v "$file" "$new"; done' _ {} +
```

I have checked these as far as I am able with test files and putting `echo` before the `mv` command, and they now seem to work.

However, it seems slightly bizarre to use the '+' option to build up a string of file names, and then to use `for` to isolate them again, so I would propose finally:

```
find . -type f -name "* - * \[*\].mp3" -execdir bash -c 'file="{}"; echo mv -v "$file" "${file%% \[*}.mp3"' \;
```

I have removed the `new` variable, as its value can be equally well expanded in-line.